# :clouchdb error with ID

Tags: insert, couchdb, common-lisp

I'm getting an error on one part of the `:clouchdb` [example code](http://common-lisp.net/project/clouchdb/#sym-document-id) (that's a link, but the `examples.lisp` file included doesn't work properly either).

Specifically, when I input

```
> (create-document '((:|name| . "wine") (:|tags| . ("beverage" "fun" "alcoholic"))))
```

I get a `DOC-ERROR` condition

```
Reason "Content-Type must be application/json", Document ID: "NIL"
   [Condition of type DOC-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {10040D2E11}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (POST-DOCUMENT ((:|name| . "wine") (:|tags| "beverage" "fun" "alcoholic")))
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CREATE-DOCUMENT '((:|name| . "wine") (:|tags| "beverage" "fun" "alcoholic"))) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 --more--
```

The intended effect of the example is to have CouchDB assign an ID to the new document (this is made clear both in the linked page and in the comments of the code file).

I'm running SBCL 1.0.40.0, clouchdb_0.0.11 (straight out of quicklisp) and CouchDB 0.11 from the Debian repos, in case it matters. I'm also on a 64-bit Debian box.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB requires a "Content-Type: application/json" when POST'ing documents, this is a fairly new requirement so I think clouchdb simply isn't doing it yet.

Shorter version: Sounds like clouchdb is not compatible with recent releases of CouchDB.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping that wasn't it. I'll see about submitting a patch, I guess. In the meantime, it turns out that [`chillax`](https://github.com/sykopomp/chillax) does support `post`ing.

Answer (score 3):

Just checked the source. Robert Newson above is correct; `clouchdb` is still setting the `content-type` to "text/javascript" while `post`ing and `put`ting documents (the latter seems to work anyway, only the post errors).

If you don't feel like using chillax as I suggest above, you can go into the clouchdb.lisp file and change the definition of `post-document` such that it sets `:content-type` to "application/json".

You should then be able to `create-document` without an `:id` set, and CouchDB will respond by generating a new one for you.

Patch based on the `quicklisp` code for `clouchdb` (not that this is complicated enough to need one):

```
--- clouchdb.lispOLD    2011-09-24 09:38:20.000000000 -0400
+++ clouchdb.lisp    2011-09-24 09:38:58.000000000 -0400
@@ -753,7 +753,7 @@
 the :ID property."
   (let ((res (ensure-db ()
                (db-request (cat (url-encode (db-name *couchdb*)) "/")
-                           :content-type "text/javascript"
+                           :content-type "application/json"
                            :external-format-out +utf-8+
                            :content-length nil
                            :method :post
```